# T-Sql group/sum query question

Tags: sql, t-sql

It's been a crappy Monday AM and I can't think straight.  Can someone help me figure out how to group/sum the rows returned so that there is only ONE instance of the AssessorParcelNumber?

So, instead of the following result set:

```
140-31-715-164  3545    2004-09-14 00:00:00.000 1665.00 0.00    0.00    1665.00
140-31-715-164  3545    2004-09-14 00:00:00.000 0.00    534.00  0.00    534.00
140-31-715-037  3546    2004-03-11 00:00:00.000 120.00  0.00    0.00    120.00
140-31-715-037  3546    2004-03-11 00:00:00.000 0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
```

I get this instead:

```
140-31-715-164  3545    2004-09-14 00:00:00.000 1665.00 534.00  0.00    2199.00
140-31-715-037  3546    2004-03-11 00:00:00.000 120.00  0.00    0.00    120.00
```

Help!  Thanks!

```
select
      u.AssessorParcelNumber,
      c.CollectionKey AS [r_number],
      c.Closed,
      CASE cd.Name1 WHEN 'Association'
            THEN CONVERT(dec(18,2),sum(t.Amount - t.AppliedAmount)) ELSE 0 END AS [assoc_balance],
      CASE cd.Name1 WHEN 'RRFS' 
            THEN CONVERT(dec(18,2),sum(t.Amount - t.AppliedAmount)) ELSE 0 END AS [rr_balance],
      CASE cd.Name1 WHEN 'RRFS' THEN 0 WHEN 'Association' THEN 0
            ELSE CONVERT(dec(18,2),sum(t.Amount - t.AppliedAmount)) END AS [_balance],
      CONVERT(dec(18,2),SUM(t.amount - t.AppliedAmount)) AS [balance]
from
      Unit u with(nolock)
      left outer join [collection] c with(nolock) on u.UnitKey = c.UnitKey
      left outer join TransactionDetail t with(nolock) on c.CollectionKey=t.CollectionKey
      left outer join TypeCode tc with(nolock) on t.PostType = tc.PostType
      left outer join CodeData cd with(nolock) on tc.Category = cd.Code2 and Code1=5
where
      t.Credit = 0 -- is a charge
      and t.Voided = 0 -- is not voided
      -- and u.AssessorParcelNumber = '140-31-715-164'
group by
      u.AssessorParcelNumber, c.CollectionKey, c.closed, cd.Name1
order by
      c.CollectionKey,
      cd.Name1;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you'd want to SUM your various balance columns.

```
SELECT
      t.AssessorParcelNumber,
      t.[r_number],
      t.Closed,
      SUM([assoc_balance]),
      SUM([rr_balance]),
      SUM([_balance]),
      SUM([balance])
    FROM (/* Insert your original query here */) t
    GROUP BY t.AssessorParcelNumber, t.r_number, t.Closed
```

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming SQL Server 2005 or better:**

I'd use your current query as a CTE then query/group by that.  I.e.:

```
;With CTE AS(


select
      u.AssessorParcelNumber,
      c.CollectionKey AS [r_number],
      c.Closed,
      CASE cd.Name1 WHEN 'Association'
            THEN CONVERT(dec(18,2),sum(t.Amount - t.AppliedAmount)) ELSE 0 END AS [assoc_balance],
      CASE cd.Name1 WHEN 'RRFS' 
            THEN CONVERT(dec(18,2),sum(t.Amount - t.AppliedAmount)) ELSE 0 END AS [rr_balance],
      CASE cd.Name1 WHEN 'RRFS' THEN 0 WHEN 'Association' THEN 0
            ELSE CONVERT(dec(18,2),sum(t.Amount - t.AppliedAmount)) END AS [_balance],
      CONVERT(dec(18,2),SUM(t.amount - t.AppliedAmount)) AS [balance]
from
      Unit u with(nolock)
      left outer join [collection] c with(nolock) on u.UnitKey = c.UnitKey
      left outer join TransactionDetail t with(nolock) on c.CollectionKey=t.CollectionKey
      left outer join TypeCode tc with(nolock) on t.PostType = tc.PostType
      left outer join CodeData cd with(nolock) on tc.Category = cd.Code2 and Code1=5
where
      t.Credit = 0 -- is a charge
      and t.Voided = 0 -- is not voided
      -- and u.AssessorParcelNumber = '140-31-715-164'
group by
      u.AssessorParcelNumber, c.CollectionKey, c.closed, cd.Name1
order by
      c.CollectionKey,
      cd.Name1)


SELECT AssessorParcelNumber, 
r_number, 
Closed, 
SUM(Assoc_balance) AS 'Assoc_Balance',
SUM(rr_balance) AS 'rr_balance',
SUM(_balance) AS '_balance',
SUM(balance) AS 'balance'
FROM CTE
GROUP BY AssessorParcelNumber, r_number, Closed
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell given the formatting of your result sets and lack of column headers, but my first guess would be that your `GROUP BY` needs to eliminate the use of cd.Name1 and use `SUM(CASE...)` in your columns.

For your column list, you can try this:

```
CAST(SUM(CASE cd.Name1
             WHEN 'Association' THEN t.Amount - t.AppliedAmount
             ELSE 0
         END) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) AS [assoc_balance],
CAST(SUM(CASE cd.Name1
             WHEN 'RRFS' THEN t.Amount - t.AppliedAmount
             ELSE 0
         END) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) AS [rr_balance],

CAST(SUM(CASE cd.Name1
             WHEN 'RRFS' THEN 0
             WHEN 'Association' THEN 0
             ELSE t.Amount - t.AppliedAmount
         END) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) AS [_balance],
```

Also, you'll need to remove the name from the `ORDER BY` as well.

Comment: I tried SUM(CASE...) but got the error:  Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Comment: I've added code to show how I think the SUM(CASE...) will need to be set up. You should actually be pulling the existing SUM out a level, not just adding a SUM on top of that. Hopefully this is clear with the example now.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
      u.AssessorParcelNumber,
      c.CollectionKey AS [r_number],
      c.Closed,
      [assoc_balance]=CONVERT(dec(18,2),SUM(CASE WHEN cd.Name1='Association' THEN t.Amount - t.AppliedAmount ELSE 0 END)),
      [rr_balance]=CONVERT(dec(18,2),SUM(CASE WHEN cd.Name1='RRFS' THEN t.Amount - t.AppliedAmount ELSE 0 END)),
      [_balance]=CONVERT(dec(18,2),SUM(CASE WHEN cd.Name1='RRFS' THEN t.Amount - t.AppliedAmount ELSE 0 END)),
      CONVERT(dec(18,2),SUM(t.amount - t.AppliedAmount)) AS [balance]
from
      Unit u with(nolock)
      left outer join [collection] c with(nolock) on u.UnitKey = c.UnitKey
      left outer join TransactionDetail t with(nolock) on c.CollectionKey=t.CollectionKey
      left outer join TypeCode tc with(nolock) on t.PostType = tc.PostType
      left outer join CodeData cd with(nolock) on tc.Category = cd.Code2 and Code1=5
where
      t.Credit = 0 -- is a charge
      and t.Voided = 0 -- is not voided
      -- and u.AssessorParcelNumber = '140-31-715-164'
group by
      u.AssessorParcelNumber, c.CollectionKey, c.closed, cd.Name1
order by
      c.CollectionKey,
      cd.Name1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem stems from including cd.Name1 in the GROUP BY clause. In the results set you listed (and I am making some assumptions here), you've got a row each for cd.Name = "Association" and "RRFS", and the group by churns that into two rows. Take that column out of the GROUP BY and move it into the case statement, something like:

```
select 
      u.AssessorParcelNumber, 
      c.CollectionKey AS [r_number], 
      c.Closed, 
      CONVERT(dec(18,2), sum(CASE cd.Name1 WHEN 'Association' THEN t.Amount - t.AppliedAmount ELSE 0 END)) AS [assoc_balance], 
      CONVERT(dec(18,2), sum(CASE cd.Name1 WHEN 'RRFS'        THEN t.Amount - t.AppliedAmount ELSE 0 END)) AS [rr_balance], 
      CONVERT(dec(18,2), sum(CASE cd.Name1 WHEN 'RRFS' THEN 0 WHEN 'Association' THEN 0 ELSE t.Amount - t.AppliedAmount END)) AS [_balance], 
      CONVERT(dec(18,2),SUM(t.amount - t.AppliedAmount)) AS [balance] 
from 
      Unit u with(nolock) 
      left outer join [collection] c with(nolock) on u.UnitKey = c.UnitKey 
      left outer join TransactionDetail t with(nolock) on c.CollectionKey=t.CollectionKey 
      left outer join TypeCode tc with(nolock) on t.PostType = tc.PostType 
      left outer join CodeData cd with(nolock) on tc.Category = cd.Code2 and Code1=5 
where 
      t.Credit = 0 -- is a charge 
      and t.Voided = 0 -- is not voided 
      -- and u.AssessorParcelNumber = '140-31-715-164' 
group by 
      u.AssessorParcelNumber, c.CollectionKey, c.closed
order by 
      c.CollectionKey, 
      cd.Name1;
```